# Apache NIFI - Fail INSERTING using PutDatabaseRecord in a table with a Enum column

Tags: database, etl, apache-nifi

I am learning/doing my first ETL with Apache Nifi, but I have a problem, the data that I am migrating comes to a JSON file and goes to a Postgres database, but it fails on the Insert part

[image]

One of the columns in the database is defined as an Enum:

`CREATE TYPE "Insurer" AS ENUM ('INSURER-A', 'INSURER-B');`

- The table has the column name as `insurer` of type `Insurer`
- And the JSON data has the field insurer as string 'INSURER-A'

Of course, the hint says that I need to do some kind of casting... but I don't have any idea about how to do it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a Record Reader with `Infer Schema` set. If so, there's no way for NiFi to know that a string/text field is an enum on the database side. To make matters worse, JDBC doesn't support Enum types per se, they are treated as strings. So in this case both NiFi and the Postgres driver think the field is a string and treat it as such, but then the Postgres DB complains that it is not the right type.

You can get by this by specifying the schema yourself. For example, using the "mood" enum specified [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html), you can use the following schema:

and then NiFi will know the incoming data is of `enum` type. However, that uncovers a bug in NiFi where we don't convert the enum type into the JDBC String type and instead report an error. I have written up [NIFI-10635](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-10635) to cover this fix, I expect it to be in the upcoming NiFi 1.19.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't do this with putdatabaserecord.
I had similar issue and I wanted to put content of flowfile as a json field to SQL Server (I had more other attribute as well).
What I did was create Insert statement with replace text and then use PutSQL processor.
The content of Replacement value was:

```
INSERT INTO rbcapi.Archive(TracingNo,Type,Content,ShamsiYearMonth,CreatedAt)
VALUES('${tracingNumber}','${messageType}','$1','${ShamsiYearMonth}','${CreatedAt}');
```

I wanted to put json value in Content field. $1 means entire content in flowfile (which was json).